# Toshiba Fan Runs on High Even when Cool

Tags: fan, toshiba-laptop

I bought a Toshiba Satellite L650 earlier this week, and have begun running into problems with it.  The fan runs perfectly when I first turn on the computer, and once I start doing something heat-inducing, the fan speeds up.  However, whenever I resume from Hibernate, the fan runs extremely quickly until I reboot.

I've updated by BIOS, and can't really think of anything else.

Does anybody here know of a possible cause for this, and maybe a solution?

Comment: Asus has really good Notebooks, they always come in at the top of independent and consumer ratings, they cost a bit more, but are worth every penny. Return that Toshiba before you regret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was posted several years ago, but I see that it's still getting views and wanted to update it with an answer:

They eventually came out with a BIOS update that fixed this problem for me. It doesn't look like it was faulty hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Toshiba laptops get many complaints for overheating.

See the last entry in this thread : [Toshiba Satellite P15 S420 Overheating](http://www.hardwareanalysis.com/content/topic/42870/).
It contains very detailed instructions how to clean the air intakes of a Toshiba Satellite.

If it is not hot, use [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) :

> SpeedFan is a program that monitors
>   voltages, fan speeds and temperatures
>   in computers with hardware monitor
>   chips. SpeedFan can even access
>   S.M.A.R.T. info and show hard disk
>   temperatures. SpeedFan supports SCSI
>   disks too. SpeedFan can even change
>   the FSB on some hardware (but this
>   should be considered a bonus feature).
>   **SpeedFan can access digital temperature sensors and can change fan
>   speeds accordingly, thus reducing
>   noise**. SpeedFan can find almost any
>   hardware monitor chip connected to the
>   2-wire SMBus (System Management Bus
>   (trademark belonging to SMIF, Inc.), a
>   subset of the I2C protocol) and works
>   fine with Windows 9x, ME, NT, 2000,
>   2003, XP, Vista and Windows 7. It
>   works with Windows 64 bit too.

Comment: It's not overheating.  The fans just running, even though it's perfectly cool.

Comment: You might have a go at using SpeedFan and seeing what the sensors are showing. It might perhaps be able to make the fans behave themselves.

Comment: I had tried Speedfan.  Unfortunately, Toshiba doesn't allow access to its fans except through the BIOS.

Comment: Then you have no other choice except activating the warranty and demanding repairs/replacement, or better (if possible) return to vendor for refund. Next time, don't buy Toshiba.